# Using Service Bus for Asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nservicebus, servicebus

I am developing Services using ASP.NET Web API and have plan to use Service Bus for message exhanging. Is it possible to use Service Bus along with ASP.NET Web API?
And what are the Microsoft's Answer for Service Bus other than Windows Azure service bus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing stopping you from using a service bus with ASP.NET Web API.

I am doing exactly this (web api) in a project I am implementing where a user registers and I need to send an activation e-mail.  The e-mail sending is handled from a service bus endpoint so that the registration from the web api returns immediately.

I have also implemented my service bus in a production system although it is MVC 3 (4 web servers).

Although any service bus should do the trick (NServiceBus, MassTransit, etc.) you may want to have a look at my FOSS Shuttle ESB project: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will experiment it, and mark it as answer. i really appreciate your reply.

Comment: Here is a twitter link to support strongly your asnwer Eben Roux. http://twitter.com/pmhsfelix/status/263202289899147264

Comment: is it possible to have a scenario where you constantly listen for a message that is sent in the service bus. let's say a topic that updates the db that the api is using is created and then the api needs to know that the db has changed (invalidate cache).

Comment: @Lyubomir Velchev: there is nothing wrong in doing what you suggest as that is a perfect scenario where a service bus / EDA is going to be handy.  No *real* business processing taking place; so it is simply a technical solution.  Absolutely fine and, in fact, I have done exactly that in previous projects.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Microsoft Service Bus 1.0?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193022(v=azure.10).aspx
(it includes messaging and queuing features from the Azure Service Bus)

For distributed caching (i.e. Caching Service in Azure)
AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server has as lot of features
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115

You can absolutely use the Caching Service in the ASP.NET Web API.  I have not tried the Microsoft Service Bus 1.0 for messaging/queuing on Web API.